# import svg as component in react without typescript reference

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I've this import in my tsx

```
import { ReactComponent as FbLogo } from '../Icons/facebook_logo.svg'
```

but I got error of
`Module '"*.svg"' has no exported member 'ReactComponent'. Did you mean to use 'import ReactComponent from "*.svg"' instead?ts(2614)`

I've no idea why, I don't understand the error. Then I saw in other repo, they added this line on the top of the file to solve it.

```
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

the error did go away, but to me it looks like a mystery. What it does exactly? Can we get rid of that? I'm using vite and typescript and react.

Comment: I assume you are using the [svgr plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-svgr) to convert SVGs to React components. Since you are using typescript you have to add a declaration helper at the top of the file for better type inference

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding this line on the top of this specific file, the best practice is to add it in the `vite-env.d.ts` file :

```
/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />
```

You should now be able to import your SVG as React Component in your app without any problem, like that :

```
import { ReactComponent as FbLogo } from '../Icons/facebook_logo.svg'
```